# Making a module global?

Tags: python, module, global

I would like to know why

```
 >>> def func2():
...     global time
...     import time
...
>>> time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
>>> func2()
>>> time
<module 'time' (built-in)>
>>>
```

works, but

```
   >>> def func():
...     global module
...     module="time"
...     exec ("global %s" %module)
...     exec ("import %s" %module)
...
>>> time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
>>> func()
>>> time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

works not, and how i could get it to work =)
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of your `exec()` calls happens in a separate namespace. Abandon this path; it will only lead to ruin.

Comment: ok thank you =) exec ("global %s;import %s" %(module,module)) works

Answer (score 1):

Because `exec` uses its own scope by default. If you do `exec "global {0}; import {0}".format(module) in globals()`, then it'll work.

You shouldn't be doing that, unless you really need to.

Comment: I don't think anybody really *needs* to use exec like this.

Comment: *Nobody* needs exec, this is Python after all.

Answer (score 1):

To import a module given the name as a string use

```
time=__import__('time')
```

Here's one way you might use it

```
usermodulenames = ["foo","bar","baz"]
usermodules = dict((k,__import__(k)) for k in usermodulenames)
```

Comment: How would i call the functions from time , when its not sure it is "time"? It would be a user input.

Comment: @Skince, you can call it whatever you like. Let me add to my answer

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is either very sophisticated or very odd. This is how it works:

```
exec ("import %s" % module) in globals()
```

Please describe the bigger problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I'm trying to import a module which the user specifies. Is there another way?

Comment: @Skince, yes there is a better way, see my answer